# .NET Core 2.2: Validate [required] properties only when object is not null

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, model-binding

I have a complex model with nested objects. I only want my `[Required]` attributes to be validated when the object they are on is not `null`. So, for example, if I have a `Home` class with an `Address` property, the `Home.Address.Street` property should only be `[required]` if the `Address` is not `null`.

#### Code

In ASP.NET Core, I have a model that looks like this:

```cs
public class Home
{
    [Required]
    public int Number {get;set;}
    public Address Address {get;set;} // This is not required
}
```

```cs
public class Address
{
   [Required]
   public string Street {get;set;}
   public IFormFile Picture {get;set;}

}
```

In a controller, I have an action method that looks like this:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public string AddHomes([FromForm]List<Home> homes) 
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
    // Do some saving
    return Ok();  
}
```

And the form payload looks like:

```
homes.Index: 0
homes[0].number: 1
```

In ASP.NET Core 2.2, the first `Home` in the `homes` list is marked as invalid, but it was working as I would expect in ASP.NET Core 2.1.

What I want is for the `[Required]` attribute to only be validated if the `Address` is not `null`. So a `Home` can *either* have an `Address` with a `Street` *or* no `Address` at all.

Is this achievable in .NET Core 2.2?

---

> **Note:** I've included an updated example below to reproduce error.
> It seems that the inclusion of `IFormFile` causes the `Address` class to initialize itself.

```
{
    "errors": {
        "homes[0].Address.Street": [
            "The Street field is required."
        ]
    },
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "80000009-0003-ff00-b63f-84710c7967bb"
}
```

I also opened an issue on GitHub for this some time ago, if anybody wants to follow up: [Inclusion of IFormFile property forces the whole object to be validated. ASP.NET Core 2.2](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/9321).

Comment: Why don't you remove [Required] from Street ??

Comment: Well it would then parse the Object as not null and there would be an Address with empty name. And also this is simplified example. I want to know how to solve the issue rather than change the intended functionality.

Comment: @Nejdi I couldn't reproduce your problem, ASP.NET Core 2.2 gave me `ModelState.IsValid == true`, did you take a look in `ModelState.Values` and see which field was invalid?

Comment: Hello @Neverever I updated the example to reproduce my error. It seems it was the inclusion of the IFormFile in the submodel that caused it to initialize itself. I also included in the updated response the BadRequestError

Comment: Did you post `IFormFile` to the correct position? i.e. `IFormFile` should be posted to `Home[1].Address.Picture`. And obviously, posting to `Home[0].Address.Picture` will trigger validation error.

Comment: The form-data looks like this
`
homes.Index: 0
homes[0].number: 1
`
And it doesn't include an Address at all. I expect it not to be validated

Comment: How do you post the file? it's the postition of the `IFormFile` causing the validation error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191718/discussion-between-nejdi-kroi-and-neverever).

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you're wanting *is* the behavior for null reference properties, and it has not changed in ASP.NET Core 2.2. The properties on the referenced class are only validated if the reference itself is non-null. If this isn't working for you, then the only conclusion is that this reference property *does* have a value. It might just be a default instantiation (i.e. `new Foo()`), with none of the sub properties actually defined, but that is enough to trigger validation.

First, ensure that you are not setting a default value for the property, or otherwise providing it a default through the contructor, for example. In other words, if you have something like:

```
public Bar Bar { get; set; } = new Bar();
```

Or,

```
public Foo()
{
    Bar = new Bar();
}
```

Remove that.

Also, realize that if *anything* is posted for that reference property, then everything comes into play. Even if you just have some hidden property like:

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Bar.Id" />
```

If any one property on the reference is posted, even if it, itself, is not valid, all validation on the class will come into play.

Comment: Hello @Chris Pratt, I updated the example to reproduce my error. It seems it was the inclusion of the IFormFile in the submodel that caused it to initialize itself. Can you take a look?